# Get child object before _id in mongo

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to get the document before the current document from an collection.
The 'problem' is that this in an child of the document.
So let's say I have this document in the 'Shops' collection:

```
{
    name: 'Test Shop',
    invoices: [
        {
            _id: ObjectId("5c642436dc12625a909d8115"),
            date: '2019-02-13 08:05:42.087Z',
            value: 0
         },
         {
            _id: ObjectId("5c6429bcc17f3d2e4c5dfb61"),
            date: '2019-02-13 14:29:16.882Z',
            value: 1
         },
         {
           _id: ObjectId("5c642b32c17f3d2e4c5dfbdd"),
            date: '2019-02-13 12:35:30.275Z',
          value: 2
         }
     ]
}
```

I have the latest invoice object with 'value: 2'
Now I want to fetch the object before this object. The object with 'value: 1'.

I'm trying to do that with this query, but It keeps me returning the first object (I think the first result for the search)

```
db.getCollection('shops').find({
    'invoices._id': { 
        $lte: ObjectId("5c642b32c17f3d2e4c5dfbdd")
     }
}, {'invoices.$':1}).sort({'invoices.date':1})
```

Is there a good way to only fetch the last result of the search, or do a good query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`$slice`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/slice/) projection

```
db.collection.find(
  { },
  { "invoices": { "$slice": -1 }}
)
```

or [**`$elemMatch`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) projection

```
db.collection.find(
  { },
  { "invoices": { "$elemMatch": { "_id": ObjectId("5c642b32c17f3d2e4c5dfbdd") }}}
)
```

Comment: Ah thanks! I modified it a little bit to get the 1 before the last by passing an array in to the $slice:
`"$slice": [*,1]` 
Where the * is, the length of the invoices array minus 2 (the last and the 1 before)